# Vb.net regex don't match if string starts with a P and contains an underscore

Tags: regex, vb.net

My regex is `\[([^P]*[^_])]`. I would like to match [ABCD] or [ABCD_D] for example, but I don't want to match if the first character in brackets starts with a P and contains an underscore. So if I came across [PABCD_23] or [Pblah_blah] regex would not match. Right now, the regex I have won't match if string contains P anywhere in the string, I think the underscore part is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use:

```
\[(?!P[^][_]*_)[^][]*]
```

**Explanation**

- `\[` Match `[`
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is to the right is not

  - `P[^][_]*_` Match a `P`, optionally any char except `[` `]` `_` and then match `_`
- `)` Close the lookahead
- `[^][]*` Optionally match any char except `[` and `]`
- `]` Match `]`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/R426kU/1).

Comment: Okay, this makes sense and does work. However, I would like to not to return the brackets, just the string as well. So it matches the [bracket] but the group should be bracket, not [bracket].

Comment: @Lord45 Ah ok, in that case you can use a capture group. See https://regex101.com/r/OxTiIY/1 or uae lookarounds See https://regex101.com/r/9y4LgP/1

Comment: Appreciate it! That worked

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can be done like this?

```
\[([^P_]).*]
```

Comment: So this does look at the first letter in brackets, but returns the first letter. I need it to return the entire string if not P..._. Without the brackets as well. Here is your example: [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/R426kU/1)